# access head javascript variable in .js file jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript variable in the head of my dom and I need to access it in an external js file but it seems to come up undefined.

In my head I have something like.

```
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var overlayAlignment = ["left:20px","right:40px","left:50px"];
</script>
    </head>
```

external .js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
alert(overlayAlignment[0]);
});
```

In my external js file I want to use the variable but something like this comes up undefined all the time, any idea what I am doing wrong.

I found that I could run a function from the external .js in the head to set the overlayAlignment variable if I add the overlayAlignment variable to the .js file.

```
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setOverlayAlignment("value1", "value2", "values3");
</script>
</head>
```

external .js file

```
function setOverlayAlignment(value1, value2, value3) {
    overlayalignment[0] = value1;
    overlayalignment[1] = value2;
    overlayalignment[2] = value3;
}
```

This still comes up as undefined when I try to use it in my jquery function however.  Strange, I thought $(document).ready was to tell the function to wait till the dom is loaded to run, if that is the case why is overlayAlignment undefined when it runs?

I need to do it like this because the overlayAlignment variable values are only known at runtime.

Comment: Did you leave off `<script>` tags in your example or is there raw JS code in the head?

Comment: I think that was the OP's mistake.

Comment: Corrected my original post, sorry I left that out.  It is there though and still not working.

Comment: Have you tried moving the "external".js code into the same script block, on the main page, just to see if it works. Should work based on what you have posted, maybe there is other code breaking and reporting this error falsely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird just tried this and it worked.  Strange I thought window.onload and $(document).ready were the same thing.

```
window.onload = function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert(overlayAlignment[0]);
    });
}
```

Apparently overlayAlignment was not ready when $(document).ready was called but it will be available after window.onload.

Answer (score 3):

You need to surround the JavaScript code in the `head` with `script` tags.

Therefore, your first example should really be:

```
<head>
<script>
var overlayAlignment = ["left:20px","right:40px","left:50px"];
</script>
</head>
```

And your second should be:

```
<head>
<script>
setOverlayAlignment("value1", "value2", "values3");
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Corrected my original post, sorry I left that out.  It is there though and still not working.